# How to find shortcut keys (⌘⌥⇧⌃) in Unicode popover?

Tags: keyboard, unicode

How do I find the keyboard shortcut Unicode characters in the popover launched by
<kbd>⌃ ctrl</kbd> <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>   <kbd>Space</kbd> (not sure of the official name, but I’m referring to the “emoji picker”)?

Note that the <kbd>⌃</kbd> I’m looking for is different from the standard caret <kbd>^</kbd>.

Answer (score 17):

- ⌘: type "place of interest" (this took me a while to figure out, had tried "point of.." and "attraction")
- ⌥ just type "option"!
- ⇧: type "upwards white arrow" (bonus: ⇪)
- ⌃: type "up arrowhead" (it's *not* the standard caret)

Bonus:

- ⌫ & ⌦: type "erase"

Answer (score 5):

*Edit: Though this method would not help for the smaller 'emoji popover' [see comments below] I'll leave it here in case future Googlers might find it useful.*

To save having to remember all their names every time, just add that category to your Character Sidebar.

At the top left, click the gear icon [it looks greyed out until you open the list, but it does work]

Click the reveal error on Symbols & add Technical Symbols.

All the standard Apple keyboard symbols are in the first few lines.

*Bonus* - if you also add Unicode [In Code Tables, way down the bottom] to the sidebar it adds the Unicode references to the preview on the right too.

[image]

*Note:*
it used to be called the 'Character Viewer', now it rather limply styles itself as 'Emoji & Symbols'... but whoever thought up that snappy name forgot to change the actual window title :/

Comment: Your answer doesn't really fit the smaller "popover" emoji-picker version of the Character Viewer.  In order to get from it to the expanded version shown here, the user has to click with the mouse on the small icon in the top right corner,

Comment: @TomGewecke - I hadn't considered that version of the char picker. tbh, the only place I've ever seen that popover is in Messages, triggered by clicking the smiley. Ctrl/Space does nothing on my machine & I can't find where to even set it.

Comment: The OP got the shortcut wrong, it's control/command/space (Edit > Emoji & Symbols).  I think the small version is actually the default for that shortcut until you change to the expanded version.  One major difference is that the search field in the small version is automatically in focus right after launch so no mouse is needed to search.

Comment: @TomGewecke - ahh, thanks for the clarification. I guess I've been using the old version so long I don't even consider using the small 'smiley' version, so either my defaults were set long before the new popover was available, or I set it day one... out of irritation ;) I'll leave this answer here in case it's useful for anyone Googling, but I appreciate it will not help the OP in this particular case.

Comment: @TomGewecke annoyingly, it was correct initially, but then it was [edited to use some different markup but be wrong](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/294120/revisions)